# Open storyboard of another project in workspace

Tags: ios, ipad, swift2

Is there a way to instantiate storyboard of another project in the same workspace? 
By using different storyboard name and pointing to its bundle.

Comment: No! or you can copy this storyboard to new project

Comment: But it has classes associated with it. Which will be in another project.

Comment: One project is in Swift and another one in objective C

Comment: @ThoNguyen. Cannot solve that with bridging headers.  I need to instantiate another storyboard in another project in same workspace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can open the storyboard of one project from another in same workspace.

Say, you have a storyboard in a framework and you want to use it in your application. Here's how you would do it from your application's code,

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.yourdomain.nameOfFramework") //getting the bundle for the framework
let storyboardFramework = UIStoryboard(name: "SM_Main", bundle: frameworkBundle) //pulling the storyboard from the framework
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed

Comment: frameworkBundle alwas nil and app crash when try to read storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Solution that succeed for my project.
Main.storyboard has a reference to a view controller in another project of workspace.

I have workspace with 2 projects:

1. **MainProject** with `Main.storyboard`
2. **TestProject** with
   `Test.storyboard` and Bundle Identifier = `com.testbundleid`

How to connect them?

In `Main.storyboard` create ***storyboard reference*** with properties:

- Storyboard = `Test` ;
- Bundle = `com.testbundleid`
- Storyboard ID = `TestViewController`

Comment: After connecting like this, How to call TestViewController from **Main.storyboard's ViewController** ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 by creating a segue in the storyboard from your first ViewController to the referenced ViewController, and triggering that as you usually would.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't tried this using external storyboards. That's what brought me here. But that's how you move between a concrete ViewController in your storyboard, and a storyboard reference.